# Elasticsearch in Python, is there a phrase suggestor?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Following this link [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html). There is a concept called "Phrase Suggestor" which uses some N-Gram methods to give you a suggestions sort of like autocompletion. I was trying to see how to use the api that Python offers docs found [here](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/api.html#text-structure). But I could not find anything mentioning n-gram or phrase suggestor.

Does this method exist in the Python Elasticsearch API? I am aware of NLTK and the n-gram methods there.

Here is what I have.

First connecting, this block of code works fine

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
CLOUD_ID = 'My_deployment:...'
ELASTIC_PASSWORD = 'password'

es = Elasticsearch(cloud_id=CLOUD_ID,
    basic_auth=("elastic", ELASTIC_PASSWORD))
```

This second block does not work

```
text = 'noble prize'
suggest_dictionary = {"simple_phrase" : {
                      'text' : text,
                      "phrase" : {
                          "field" : "title.trigram"
                      }
                    }
                  }

query_dictionary = {'suggest' : suggest_dictionary}

res = es.search(
    index='test',
    body=query_dictionary)
print(res)
```

The error message is this

```
<ipython-input-29-05c434577314>:12: DeprecationWarning: The 'body' parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instead use individual parameters.
  res = es.search(

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-05c434577314> in <module>
     10 query_dictionary = {'suggest' : suggest_dictionary}
     11 
---> 12 res = es.search(
     13     index='test',
     14     body=query_dictionary)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/utils.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    402                         pass
    403 
--> 404             return api(*args, **kwargs)
    405 
    406         return wrapped  # type: ignore[return-value]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/__init__.py in search(self, index, aggregations, aggs, allow_no_indices, allow_partial_search_results, analyze_wildcard, analyzer, batched_reduce_size, ccs_minimize_roundtrips, collapse, default_operator, df, docvalue_fields, error_trace, expand_wildcards, explain, fields, filter_path, from_, highlight, human, ignore_throttled, ignore_unavailable, indices_boost, lenient, max_concurrent_shard_requests, min_compatible_shard_node, min_score, pit, post_filter, pre_filter_shard_size, preference, pretty, profile, q, query, request_cache, rescore, rest_total_hits_as_int, routing, runtime_mappings, script_fields, scroll, search_after, search_type, seq_no_primary_term, size, slice, sort, source, source_excludes, source_includes, stats, stored_fields, suggest, suggest_field, suggest_mode, suggest_size, suggest_text, terminate_after, timeout, track_scores, track_total_hits, typed_keys, version)
   3697         if __body is not None:
   3698             __headers["content-type"] = "application/json"
-> 3699         return self.perform_request(  # type: ignore[return-value]
   3700             "POST", __path, params=__query, headers=__headers, body=__body
   3701         )

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/_base.py in perform_request(self, method, path, params, headers, body)
    319                     pass
    320 
--> 321             raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(meta.status, ApiError)(
    322                 message=message, meta=meta, body=resp_body
    323             )

NotFoundError: NotFoundError(404, 'index_not_found_exception', 'no such index [test]', test, index_or_alias)
```

The answer provided states to use the `PUT test` to setup the index. Where? no idea... how? no idea... I am not familiar with that syntax and Python does not seem to be able to recognize it either.

**Update**

I was able to get it to work finally, but I am confused by the output

```
{'took': 1, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 0, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}, 'suggest': {'simple_phrase': [{'text': 'Hi, I need help', 'offset': 0, 'length': 15, 'options': []}]}}
```

Where is the recommendation? aka the autocompletion to finish the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You can first create index mapping with so you not need to depends on external python Ngram and Elasticsearch store field internally after generating NGram.

**Index Mapping**

```json
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "trigram": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": ["lowercase","shingle"]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "shingle": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "trigram": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "trigram"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use below python code for Phrase Suggestor and provided body same as mentioned in documentation.

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

text = 'noble prize'
suggest_dictionary = {"simple_phrase" : {
                      'text' : text,
                      "phrase" : {
                          "field" : "title.trigram"
                      }
                    }
                  }

query_dictionary = {'suggest' : suggest_dictionary}

res = es.search(
    index='test',
    body=query_dictionary)
print(res)
```

**Update 1:**

> The answer provided states to use the PUT test to setup the index.
> Where? no idea... how? no idea... I am not familiar with that syntax
> and Python does not seem to be able to recognize it either.

`put test` is for creating index in Elasticsearch. So if you have `kibana` install then you can goto `dev console` and execute it. otherwise you can use same with `curl` command as well. If you have exsitig index then you can give your index name as well insted of `test`.

[This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html) will show how to use curl command for index creation.

[This](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create) will show how to use python for creating index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer this is really helpful, do you know what type of n-gram method that is? From what I read, elastic search supports stupid_backoff, laplace. and linear interpolation

Comment: I also received this error `ValueError: Either 'hosts' or 'cloud_id' must be specified`

Comment: you need to provide your host information likle `es = Elasticsearch(['https://user:secret@localhost:443'])` in your code. I just posted sample code in answer. You can see the elasticsearch python documentation [here](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/)

Comment: For understanding ngram please check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) documentation. it will give you clear understanding of how NGram generated in elasticsearch and diffrent configuration option.

Comment: I got it to work but I get this using your example: `NotFoundError: NotFoundError(404, 'index_not_found_exception', 'no such index [test]', test, index_or_alias)`

Comment: What am I suppose to do with the `PUT test` part, I am not famaliar with that syntax nor does Python recognize it

Comment: @justanewb `put test` is for creating index in Elasticsearch. So if you have `kibana` install then you can goto `dev console` and execute it. otherwise you can use same with `curl` command as well. If you have exsitig index then you can give your index name as well insted of `test`.

Comment: Can you please show me how to create index in Python? The docs are still unclear to me.

Comment: can you please check [this](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-map-an-elasticsearch-index-using-the-python-client-266) guide for sample code.